# IHP - How to send and receive data between clients via custom Web Socket controller?

Tags: haskell, ihp

I'm building a chat application with a custom web socket controller and I want to establish a two way communication between different clients with the server in the middle in such a way that whenever a client sends a request, it gets updated on the server and the server emits a response to all the clients.

Note: I've tried using [IHP's Auto Refresh](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/auto-refresh.html) but using that is turning out to be [quite expensive](https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1188) for my use case  so that's why I'm trying to set up a custom web socket controller.

Comment: I'm actually using IHP, a Haskell web framework for building my web app, not PHP.

Comment: My apologies - I've removed my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the new IHP DataSync API: https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/realtime-spas.html

It's higher level than websockets but likely can help you implement the chat app.